# Is there a way to make my CSS overlay take over the whole page? Stuck in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm attempting to create a decent button banner for my site because the text navigation makes the page look really wonky.

When clicking on any of the three buttons a curtain menu slides down into place. The problem is that I'm using Google Sites and the code has to be embedded within a frame. I tried the iframe suggestion below but can't get it to work properly. Can I display it as a pop-up?

I need the curtain menu to jump out of its frame and cover the entire page. I've tried changing the position and overflow elements to no avail.

I'm a complete noob. It's taken me a week to get to this point and have been attempting to figure out this curtain menu for two days. I'm a little burned out on it - probably something simple that I'm missing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      gap: 10px;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;
      padding top: 30px
    }
    
    .overlay {
      height: 0%;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow: scroll;
      text-align: center;
      transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .overlay a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 24px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .overlay a:hover,
    .overlay a:focus {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .overlay-content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: relative;
      top: 25%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .closebtnOverlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      right: 45px;
      font-size: 50px !important;
    }
    
    .button {
      background-color: #FF8C00;
      border: 2px solid #338C9A;
      border-radius: 12px;
      color: white;
      width: 120px;
      height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .overlay a {
        font-size: 20px
      }
      .closebtnOverlay {
        font-size: 40px !important;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtnOverlay" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Phoenix</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Prescott</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Scottsdale</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tucson</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myNav2" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtnOverlay" onclick="closeNav2()">×</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Cape Coral</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Jacksonville</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Lakeland</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Miami</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Ocala</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Orlando</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Palm Beach</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Pensacola</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Port Charlotte</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sarasota</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">St. Augustine</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">St. Petersburg</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tallahasse</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tampa</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myNav3" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtnOverlay" onclick="closeNav3()">×</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Austin</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Dallas</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Houston</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">San Antonio</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="button" onclick="openNav()">Arizona</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="openNav2()">Florida</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="openNav3()">Texas</button>
  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    }

    function openNav2() {
      document.getElementById("myNav2").style.height = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav2() {
      document.getElementById("myNav2").style.height = "0%";
    }

    function openNav3() {
      document.getElementById("myNav3").style.height = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav3() {
      document.getElementById("myNav3").style.height = "0%";
    }
  </script>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Need an opening `<body>`

Comment: you forget to add opening `body` tag.

Comment: No you can not pop out of the iframe when it is a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to cover the whole page if you are using an iframe. Another solution to handle situations is you can change the iframe style.

```
<iframe src="http://www.youraddress.com" frameborder="0" style="height:100%;width:100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Does the URL need to be changed for each page the code is in or just point it to the main URL?
Also, where in the code would this be inserted?

Comment: Tried the iframe suggestion in multiple areas of the code. It seems to display the same way no matter where I put it and i's still not displaying properly. Can I make it a pop-up?

Comment: Let me understand first what you are trying to do.
1) webpage hosting on like xyz.com
2) you have to show on google sites that use an iframe to show your page

Please do correct me if I'm understanding wrong.
Thanks

Comment: I have my own domain name, yes. The site, however, is a free site through Google Sites.